# Iterating through properties of a class and creation of a simple Object consolidating information

Tags: c#, .net, class, properties, ienumerable

I have the following class

```
 public class ScanDetails
 {
    public Lavasoft Lavasoft { get; set; }
    public STOPzilla STOPzilla { get; set; }
    public Zillya Zillya { get; set; }
    public VirusBlokAda VirusBlokAda { get; set; }
    public TrendMicro TrendMicro { get; set; }
    public SUPERAntiSpyware SUPERAntiSpyware { get; set; }
    public NProtect nProtect { get; set; }
    public NANOAV NANOAV { get; set; }
 }
```

Each sub property is a separate class like this

```
public class Lavasoft
{
    public int scan_time { get; set; }
    public DateTime def_time { get; set; }
    public int scan_result_i { get; set; }
    public string threat_found { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to get the names of all classes whose `threat_found` property !=""

I have tried iterating through the properties

```
 foreach (var prop in report.scan_results.scan_details.GetType().GetProperties())
 {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", prop.Name, prop.GetValue("threat_found", null));
 }
```

But i keep getting the following exception -> Object does not match the desired type

Comment: Why using separate properties when the corresponding classes seems to share common  properties? Those common properties could (should!) be regrouped in a base class or an interface and then you could use a `List` or whatever of the base class/interface

Comment: @Cid I have created the classes based on JSON returned by https://onlinehelp.opswat.com/mdcloud/2.2_Retrieving_scan_reports_using_data_ID.html   `Report myresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Report>(responseBody);`

Comment: instead of a loop over GetProperties() try GetProperty("threat_found") then invoke that

Comment: @user326608 But `scandetails` contains multiple values.

Comment: @techno see answer. you could also use a linq select

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class ScanDetail
{
    public int scan_time { get; set; }
    public DateTime def_time { get; set; }
    public int scan_result_i { get; set; }
    public string threat_found { get; set; }
}

public class ScanDetails
 {
    public ScanDetail Lavasoft { get; set; }
    public ScanDetail STOPzilla { get; set; }
    public ScanDetail Zillya { get; set; }
    public ScanDetail VirusBlokAda { get; set; }
    public ScanDetail TrendMicro { get; set; }
    public ScanDetail SUPERAntiSpyware { get; set; }
    public ScanDetail nProtect { get; set; }
    public ScanDetail NANOAV { get; set; }
 }


 foreach (var prop in report.scan_results.scan_details.GetType().GetProperties())
 {
    if(prop.PropertyType is ScanDetail)
    {
        var scan_detail = prop.GetValue(report.scan_results.scan_details) as ScanDetail;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1} = {2}", prop.Name, "threat_found", scan_detail.threat_found);    
    }
    
 }
```

Comment: Thanks,but `scan_detail` does not have `threat-found` property .

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

> prop.GetValue("threat_found", null)

You are trying to get 'Lavasoft' property from string "threat_found" with index null.

This works:

```
        foreach (var prop in report.scan_results.scan_details.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var threatFoundPropOfCurrentType = prop.PropertyType.GetProperty("threat_found");
            var threatFoundValueOfCurrentType = threatFoundPropOfCurrentType.GetValue(prop.GetValue(report.scan_results.scan_details)) as string;
            Console.WriteLine($"{prop.Name} = {threatFoundValueOfCurrentType}");
        }
```

Comment: What specifically is the problem?

Comment: I'm trying a different approach now.. please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62851551/converting-json-to-array-using-newtonsoft-json-results-in-error